# How Can I Add an Expand/Close Icon to My App?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have created an expandable/collapsible list after following a tutorial for my app in Android Studio, however I'm wanting to add a button which is aligned left of the heading which changes to an up/down button when a heading is expanded/collapsed. How can I add this?

My activity files for the expandable and collapsible list are as follows:

list_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#f4f4f4" >

<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/lvExp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

list_group.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="8dp"
android:background="#000000">


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:textColor="#f9f93d" />

</LinearLayout>
```

list_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="55dip"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="17dip"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I've tried to implement it by changing the layout file of list_group.xml to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="8dp"
android:background="#000000">


<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/down_squared"  android:state_checked="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/up_squared"  android:state_checked="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</selector>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:textColor="#f9f93d" />

</LinearLayout>
```

However the page keeps crashing now and there the design tab says there are rendering errors, which are:

The following classes could not be found:
- item (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)
- selector (Fix Build Path, Edit XML)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use checkbox with background set as your drawable

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/play_icon" android:state_checked="true" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/pause_icon" android:state_checked="false" />
</selector>
```

then in your code set a callback for checkbox [setOnCheckedChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener))

and inside the [onCheckedChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener.html#onCheckedChanged(android.widget.CompoundButton,%20boolean)) put [expandGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#expandGroup(int)) and [collapseGroup](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html#collapseGroup(int)) calls, depending on the check state

Comment: Hi, there is a default icon in list_main.xml which changes from up to down when I expand a group and vice versa, is there any way in which I can change the icon used for this and its colour? I can't see to find the property. Thanks

Comment: Yes, there is a way. Just change @drawable/down_squared and @drawable/up_squared to something else. You can change it's color applying an icon with wanted color or you can use the color filter using setColorFilter on drawable. You're doing it wrong by the way. You shouldn't put selector in your layout but the checkbox with background set to to that selector.